# What is the best JQuery plugin that handles HTML5 location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, geospatial

I want to get the lat/long for a browser.

I know that HTML5 has the feature, but I want a full plugin that handles old browsers gracefully.

Is there a reliable plugin for this?

Comment: How should this plugin handle old browsers? They simply don't have the functionality.

Comment: I'd recommend using a server-side ip detection based service.

Comment: Found this? Not sure if it's what you're looking for:

https://github.com/teleject/HTML5-GeoLocation-jQuery-Plugin/blob/master/README

Comment: Maybe this one could help: https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim/blob/master/src/shims/geolocation.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need a plugin for something so simple ?

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
}else{
   errorFunction();
}

function successFunction(position) { //uses HTML5 if available
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
}

function errorFunction(){ //uses IP if no HTML5
   $.getJSON("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function(res){
        var lat = res.latitude;
        var lng = res.longitude;
   });
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xcP9K/1/)

This checks if the HTML5 geolocation API is supported, if it is, it gets the coordinates, if it's not, or if the HTML5 geo API for some reason fails, it uses a free geoIP service to get the coordinates.

Comment: @TIMEX - Yes, it falls back to a IP based solution, so it should work anywhere.

Comment: Thanks. What about Google GEARS? Does that help at all?

Comment: If the user has GEARS installed, sure! I tend to just stick with HTML5 as a first choice, as it's fastest and most accurate, and fallback to IP adress it it's not supported, and these days IP geolocation is'nt that bad, and it's pretty fast, and somewhat accurate. Not sure how GEARS would perform, as I haven't used it for years, and I don't think anyone really has.