# HTML5 GEOLocation 2nd prompt

Tags: html, geolocation

Is there a way to prompt user for geolocation again on some trigger, after they denied the location sharing?

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
```

fires it once, consecutive calls do not produce the same result. Cant find the answer anywhere/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this Code Snippet and this SO Answer:  [What is the best JQuery plugin that handles HTML5 location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046508/what-is-the-best-jquery-plugin-that-handles-html5-location/15046747#15046747)

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
}else{
   errorFunction();
}

function successFunction(position) { //uses HTML5 if available
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
}

function errorFunction(){ //uses IP if no HTML5
   $.getJSON("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function(res){
        var lat = res.latitude;
        var lng = res.longitude;
   });
}
```

Take a Look at this [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/sandesh2302/FghFZ/) Link also
[`JQuery Geolocator Plugin`](http://krister.fi/jquery.geolocator/)

Comment: Does this actually solve the problem in question here (that the prompt to allow geolocation lookup does not come up again after it’s been denied once) …? I doubt it.

Comment: does not answer my question though

Comment: I guess the only way to work around it is to refresh the page( if its an option) to be able to prompt again.

Answer (score 0):

## In Geolocation API? No.

If user clicks deny permission it simply means "No, and don't bother me again..."

However user can do it by deleting Location-share-settings, then of course the prompt pops out again.

Or user can just change the settings if browser allows it, however e.g. Chrome manages these settings as exceptions (no matter whether user've allowed or denied permission) so user have to delete the settings, resp. exception anyway.

## What now?

Your only option is to catch the error and use e.g. some external API to find the user's location by IP. You can program it by yourself or there are of course existing solutions as @Venkat suggested.

But be aware IP geolocation is a tricky one - sometimes it has an adress-number-accuracy sometimes it's just state-accuracy.

This examle [from Mozilla's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation.getCurrentPosition) shows a nice example how to handle Geolocation errors:

```
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;

  console.log('Your current position is:');
  console.log('Latitude : ' + crd.latitude);
  console.log('Longitude: ' + crd.longitude);
  console.log('More or less ' + crd.accuracy + ' meters.');
};

function error(err) {
  /*
  CALL EXTERNAL API HERE
  */
  console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option for this is to setup a geolocation subdomain, and load it in a iframe.

```
geo-0.domain.com
geo-1.domain.com
geo-2.domain.com
geo-3.domain.com
geo-4.domain.com
geo-N.domain.com
```

This will allow you unlimited attempts on every browser, all you need to do is program in your own retry logic.